# Difference between useRef and onBlur?

Tags: javascript

I am confused about the usages of useref and onBlur in JS...I need suggestions on when to use both of these and the functionality of them.

Comment: You mean `useRef` from React.js? If yes, please tag your question with it.

Comment: I don't see how they are related in any way. Can you please show some examples of code where both are used and you are confused about them? Or state a problem where you are wondering which of them to use, where you think both could work (and how)?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think there's is much of a similarity between those two. `useRef` is a react hook whereas `onBlur` is an event handler.

[`userRef`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) allows you to create mutable objects within a react functional component, so you can have a value that persists across renders. The hook returns an object with a `current` property where the mutable object reference lives. Usually it is also used to create a reference to the dom node of a certain element, and this way you can work imperatively with the dom node by doing for example `yourRef.current.focus()`

[`onBlur`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/blur_event) on other hand is an event handler that you can attach to elements (usually inputs) to call back on the event when the element loses focus. I think of `blur` as the opposite of `focus`.